# Similar strings causing IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a `pandas df` that contains various functions and timestamps. I'm trying to efficiently return the differences between different functions.

This is a very small sample of the `df`. `Col C` represents the functions, `B` displays timestamps, `D` displays different places, `E` displays the amount of occurrences. Essentially, I want to return the difference between functions at different places. These functions occur numerous times.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'B' : [10,20,35,50],
    'C' : ['Stop','Close','Open','Finish'],
    'D' : ['Home','Home Kitchen','Home','Home'],          
    'E' : [1,1,1,1],          
    })
```

I'm currently doing this via:

```
def f(g):
    Stop = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Stop', 'B']
    Finish = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Finish', 'B']
    Open = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Open', 'B']
    g['YX_diff'] = Finish.values[0] - Stop.values[0]
    g['YZ_diff'] = Finish.values[0] - Open.values[0]

    return (g)
```

I have a list of places that I perform this loop on. The above df only displays Home but it can be numerous places. To apply this I include the following:

```
included = ['Home']

df = df[df.D.isin(included)].groupby(['D', 'E']).apply(f)
```

The problem I'm having is the places I want to look at. Specifically, if the strings are similar. For example:

```
included = ['Home']
```

Works fine. But if I include

```
included = ['Home','Home Kitchen']
```

it returns an error:

```
    g['YX_diff'] = Finish.values[0] - Stop.values[0]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I don't want to change the strings as they represent specific information. I'm not sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem for string `Home Kitchen` all 3 filtered `Series` are empty, so is not possible select first value.

```
s = pd.Series()
print (s)
Series([], dtype: float64)

print (s.values[0])
```

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

You can check it:

```
def f(g):
    Stop = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Stop', 'B']
    Finish = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Finish', 'B']
    Open = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Open', 'B']
    print (Stop)
    print (Finish)
    print (Open)
#    g['YX_diff'] = Finish.values[0] - Stop.values[0]
#    g['YZ_diff'] = Finish.values[0] - Open.values[0]

    return (g)

included = ['Home', 'Home Kitchen']

df = df[df.D.isin(included)].groupby(['D', 'E']).apply(f)

0    10
Name: B, dtype: int64
3    50
Name: B, dtype: int64
2    35
Name: B, dtype: int64
0    10
Name: B, dtype: int64
3    50
Name: B, dtype: int64
2    35
Name: B, dtype: int64
Series([], Name: B, dtype: int64)
Series([], Name: B, dtype: int64)
Series([], Name: B, dtype: int64)
```

---

Possible solution is `if-else` for these strings - e.g. set to `NaN`s:

```
def f(g):
    Stop = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Stop', 'B']
    Finish = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Finish', 'B']
    Open = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Open', 'B']
    Stop = np.nan if len(Stop) == 0 else Stop.values[0]
    Finish = np.nan if len(Finish) == 0 else Finish.values[0]
    Open = np.nan if len(Open) == 0 else Open.values[0]

    g['YX_diff'] = Finish - Stop
    g['YZ_diff'] = Finish - Open

    return (g)

included = ['Home', 'Home Kitchen']

df = df[df.D.isin(included)].groupby(['D', 'E']).apply(f)
print (df)
    B       C             D  E  YX_diff  YZ_diff
0  10    Stop          Home  1     40.0     15.0
1  20   Close  Home Kitchen  1      NaN      NaN
2  35    Open          Home  1     40.0     15.0
3  50  Finish          Home  1     40.0     15.0
```

Another solution in pure python, `next` has optional argument, which is `NaN`, if there are no elements to extract:

```
def f(g):
    Stop = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Stop', 'B']
    Finish = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Finish', 'B']
    Open = g.loc[df['C'] == 'Open', 'B']

    Stop_first = next(iter(Stop), np.nan)
    Finish_first = next(iter(Finish), np.nan)
    Open_first = next(iter(Open), np.nan)

    g['YX_diff'] = Finish_first - Stop_first
    g['YZ_diff'] = Finish_first - Open_first

    return (g)

included = ['Home', 'Home Kitchen']

df = df[df.D.isin(included)].groupby(['D', 'E']).apply(f)
```

Comment: Legend @jezrael